# Delete elements from a list while minimizing the number of unique sub-elements

Tags: python

I have a list of `recipes` and a list of `ingredients`.

Each `recipe` is defined by one or more set(s) of ingredients.

This means that some recipes have more than 1 way of being accomplished.

A simple example:

```
recipe1 = (("egg", "salt", "pepper"))
recipe2 = (("egg", "carrot", "ham"), ("cream", "carrot", "ham"))
recipes = (recipe1, recipe2)
```

I want to simplify `recipes` by deleting some set of ingredients.

- I want only one `set` per `recipe`
- I want the list of `unique_ingredients` to be as small as possible

If I delete `("egg", "carrot", "ham")` from `recipe2`, `recipes` will become `(("egg", "salt", "pepper"),("cream", "carrot", "ham"))`, which has 6 unique elements `("egg", "salt", "pepper", "cream", "carrot", "ham")`

While if I delete `("cream", "carrot", "ham")` from `recipe2`, `recipes` will become `(("egg", "salt", "pepper"),("egg", "carrot", "ham"))`, which has 5 unique elements `("egg", "salt", "pepper", "carrot", "ham")`

How would you proceed to delete the set of elements while minimizing the number of unique elements?

Comment: Is `recipe1` a tuple of tuples? The extra parentheses seem redundant.

Comment: Also, let me clarify: given a collection of recipes, we want to pick one set of three ingredients from each recipe such that the total number of unique ingredients from the selected sets is minimized. Is that correct?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I added the parentheses in order to give the same depth to all recipes

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark YES, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check through the cartesian product of ingredients (`it.product`) and pick the combination with the fewest items (`min` over `len(set(...))`).

```
recipe1 = (("egg", "salt", "pepper"), )
recipe2 = (("egg", "carrot", "ham1"), ("cream", "carrot", "ham"))
recipes = (recipe1, recipe2)


import itertools as it

recipe_and_sizes = [(len(set(it.chain(*x))), x) for x in it.product(*recipes)]
recipes = min(recipe_and_sizes)[1]
print(recipes)

(('egg', 'salt', 'pepper'), ('egg', 'carrot', 'ham1'))
>
```

Comment: This is really great, however, if the number of recipes is too great (I have 301 groups of recipe with 2 ingredients, and between only one to 40+ possibilities), I quickly get a "memory error". Any idea for an approach that may not be exact but does not requires 1To of RAM and a week to compute?